# Robocopy extremely low performance copying from Synlogy SMB

Tags: windows, backup, nas, smb, robocopy

I want to occasionally backup a media library which is located on my NAS to another drive (6TB WD RED HDD; produced in 2019). The drive is located in my main PC and connected through SATA.

The NAS and my PC are linked via a 1 Gb/s Ethernet switch. From other tasks I know that this connection is in fact capable of delivering close to 1 Gb/s in performance. This is also supported by a quick tested using Windows Explorer to copy a movie from the NAS -> HDD:

[image: screenshot of Windows Explorer File Transfer]

The whole 23.5GB file was transfered at ~80MB/s speed which I deem very usable.

For the actual backup I wanted to use `robocopy` which schould be able to be scheduled and also detect whether a copy is even necessary etc. pp.
But when I tried out robocopy with any of the following commands, Task-Manager reported only about 30 MBit/s of network traffic and the copy took very long:

- `robocopy "\\NasName\Media\ " "F:\MediaBackup\ " /MIR /XO /Z /MT:8`
- `robocopy "\\NasName\Media\ " "F:\MediaBackup\ " /MIR /XO /Z /MT:1`
- `"\\NasName\Media\" "F:\MediaBackup\" /LOG:"Backup_2023-11-25.log" /ipg:200 /NP /NC /BYTES /NJH /NJS /zb /e /compress /tee`

The last command stems from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21209726/8383428) .

Can you help me figuring out why `robocopy` has such poor performance? I would really like to use its `/ZB` or `/MIR` feature to backup my media.